# Chinese version of "beat around the bush"

Tags: translation, idioms

Most people know the famous english idiom:

> beat around the bush

How should I write this in Chinese?

Cambridge dictionary gives:

> Don't beat around the bush - get to the point! 别兜圈子了——有话直说！

But I feel it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`拐弯抹角` is a good choice, even verified by google trandlate and other websites:

- [Yellow Bridge Dictionary](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php?searchMode=E&word=beat+around+the+bush)
- [Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-chinese/beat+around+the+bush)

Answer (score 0):

> `beat around the bush` could also mean 徒勞無功。

Referring to https://drive.google.com/file/d/1avg8v2ra_Mx-UsRijLAu3GBPi5oaQ-4S/view?usp=sharing

> As an example, 別帶系統“兜圈子” or `inhibitors for COVID-19 — A miracle waiting to happen or just another beat around the bush`

`beat around the bush` could have the indication of 徒勞無功 .

Answer (score 0):

東扯西拉/閃閃爍爍, 拐弯抹角, 繞(兜)圈子 - discuss a matter without coming to the point directly, or giving a straight answer.